# Where is the "terrain.png" file located in Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I have tried to search for it in my `home` directory and my `.minecraft` directory without any success. `find / -name terrain.png` also outputs nothing.

Comment: "terrian.png"? Did you make that typo when searching for it, or is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the .jar files? If it's in there, find won't find it. If you have trouble opening the .jar, I know for sure that 7zip can do it. However, I think that 7zip for linux is command line only.

Comment: @Kotsu sorry it was just in the title. I fixed it. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar` - it's inside the jar archive. If you use a texturepack, then it's in its zip file in `~/.minecraft/texturepacks` instead. For more info take a look [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/216168-guide-how-to-make-a-texture-pack-on-mac-and-for-windows/).