# Where is the button press sound file for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a Slender Map + Resource Pack for Minecraft, and I need to change the click button sound (Stone Button, not GUI button) in the resource pack to the pick up note sound from Slender, but I don't know where the sound file is for pushing a button.

Comment: I'm unclear why this was put on hold. We've accepted [questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/how-do-i-make-a-custom-texture-pack-for-minecraft-16x16) [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27967/where-is-the-terrain-png-file-located-in-linux/27970) [modifying](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37446/how-to-replace-the-enchanting-alphabet-in-minecraft) game resources before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path in your resource pack should be

```
/assets/minecraft/sound/random/click.ogg
```

Putting a sound file there will replace the click sound. The original file is located at

```
.minecraft/assets/sound/random/click.ogg
```